# How to set id for ruby tag for capybara

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

How to set id for `<%= raw @post.body %>`?
Something like `<%= raw @post.body(id: "body") %>`
I need it for capybara tests. It shows

> Failure/Error: expect(:page).to have_content(title: "mugenseikatsu")
>   expected to find text "{:title=>\"mugenseikatsu\"}" in "page"

. I want capybara to see this id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on exactly what you're trying to do, or why, but from the error message it sounds like you're trying to test the <title> element of the page?  `have_content` takes a string of visible text to find in the current scope, it doesn't take a hash.  If you're trying to test the title of the page you should be using `have_title`

```
expect(page).to have_title("mugenseikatsu")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your way of thinking is absolutely right. After i changed it i got `Failure/Error: expect(:page).to have_title("mugenseikatsu") NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: page shouldn't be a symbol, please recheck what I put in my answer

Comment: I apologize for my inattention. Thank you, it works now :D